# Can we change Account's Default Reminders and Expiration through DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi, reminders

We want to **change DocuSign account's default reminder and expiration settings using DocuSign REST API**. Is there any API available so we can manage it.

I know we can set reminder and expiration settings on envelope notification but we want to change **default reminder and expiration settings of account through the API**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the Account wide notification settings using the **Reminders and Expirations** page on the DocuSign Admin site.

More information [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-reminders-and-expirations)

REST Api does not support this operation.